# Graph API's search returning considerately less public posts than Facebook's user facing search?

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an application based on facebook's data using the Graph API. Part of the functionality entails searching Facebook's public post, essentially in the same fashion that Facebook does on www.facebook.com/search:

http://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=thanksgiving&type=eposts&init=quick&tas=0.31611707084812224

However, when I issue the same search via the Graph API, the results return miss many of the posts shown in the standard user interface. Many of the most recent posts returned by the standard search are missing (replace the access_token to the one you have):

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=thanksgiving&type=post&access_token=XXXX

Does anyone have an idea what can cause this and how I can work around it? I have customer questioning the quality of my application because of this difference.

Many thanks,
Boaz

Answer (score 0):

That is because the Graph API uses pagination if it returns too many objects, if you take a look on the bottom of the response of the "Nike" search you will find this:

```
"paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=nike&type=post&access_token=XX&limit=25&since=1322257702&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=nike&type=post&access_token=XX&limit=25&until=1322246079"
   }
```

Just make another request to the "next" url in order to fetch more results.

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue - I am missing many of the most recent results which should have been in the first page.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I have tried to reproduce your issue without any success, only thing I notice is that the search on the web page refreshes automatically. So there might become a missmatch if you don't compare data from the same time.