# How does the Facebook Graph API public post searching works?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've started working with Facebook Graph API this month and I'm currently experiencing some odd behaviors with it.

To start, I'm using the Graph API 1.0 (which supports public post searching), with queries such as those below.

- https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=foo bar&type=post
- https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=foo&type=post

The weird behavior in this case is that the first query returns almost the same number of results that the second one. Thus, no matter how "vague" my query is, I'm getting a limited number of posts (yeah, I'm already considering pagination).

So how does this work? The Graph API Documentation isn't clear about this subject, so any clarification would be really appreciated.

1. As I understood so far, Facebook does not return *all* public posts containing the researched terms. Some old questions here in StackTrace support this assumption ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377275/cant-find-my-post-through-facebooks-search-api))
2. Different apps or different users may retrieve different results (which is another "odd" behavior I found). ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274444/graph-apis-search-returning-considerately-less-public-posts-than-facebooks-use))

Am I correct? If so, is there ANY way to improve my recall? Any paid services from Facebook or specific permissions that I should get for my app? Searching from multiple views (users or apps) would help? Is there any way to query only recent results and therefore obtain more results?

Thank you.

P.S.: I'm aware that Facebook has been planning to remove this functionality by 2015, but for now it's working and I wanted to give a try :-)

Comment: Number 2 is pretty logical. The result is made is best as possible for the user.

Comment: Yeah it makes sense for users, but what about the apps? How is "best as possible" defined in this case?

Comment: Explaining a little bit more: I created two apps for test purposes (I just use their app token). Each app returns different results for the same query. Seems weird to me, it looks completely random.

Comment: Which access token did you use in both cases?

Comment: I'm actually relying on fbconsole library to authenticate and generate the access token. It uses the auth method based on the app_secret and the app_id provided by Facebook.

Comment: How you create the access token is not very important. What more important is what kind of access token you are using. Is it a user access token, page access token or an app access token?